# Yii2 redirecting isn't working. Why?

Tags: php, yii2

I am newbie in Yii2, and now I build new app manually (using Mark Safronov book). 
I tried to redirect my controller to somewhere and it isn't working.

Like this:

```
return $this->redirect(array('/site/dashboard'));
```

I think it depends on my settings, do you have any ideas? I'm using niceurls and this is my httaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

It is my View code

[image: my view]

And I had next config: common/config/bootstrap.php

```php
Yii::setAlias('yii2_book', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/yii2_book');
```

Code in my controller:

```html
public function actionAdd()
    {
        $customer = new CustomerRecord();
        $phone = new PhoneRecord();
        if($customer->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $customer->validate() && $phone->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
            $this->store($this->makeCustomer($customer, $phone));
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }
        return $this->render('add',compact('customer','phone'));
```

Stack trace:

```html
2018-01-05 11:30:03 [::1][-][-][error][yii\web\HttpException:400] yii\web\BadRequestHttpException: Unable to verify your data submission. in /Users/sergejandrejkin/PhpstormProjects/yii2_book/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php:166
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/sergejandrejkin/PhpstormProjects/yii2_book/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(155): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#1 /Users/sergejandrejkin/PhpstormProjects/yii2_book/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): yii\base\Controller->runAction('add', Array)
#2 /Users/sergejandrejkin/PhpstormProjects/yii2_book/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('customers/add', Array)
#3 /Users/sergejandrejkin/PhpstormProjects/yii2_book/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#4 /Users/sergejandrejkin/PhpstormProjects/yii2_book/web/index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#5 {main}
2018-01-05 11:30:03 [::1][-][-][info][application] $_POST = [
    '_csrf' => 'oUDxUGHONyj8ER3vQc9cvdpMsCJh6DXlPzsnxRCxfu3AArIlA7lYR8tnbN8UuDf_937iFlKnc6tGVhCNQvQKiA=='
    'CustomerRecord' => [
        'name' => ''
        'birth_date' => ''
        'notes' => ''
    ]
    'PhoneRecord' => [
        'number' => ''
    ]
]

$_SERVER = [
    'REDIRECT_STATUS' => '200'
    'HTTP_HOST' => 'localhost:8888'
    'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'keep-alive'
    'CONTENT_LENGTH' => '208'
    'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => 'max-age=0'
    'HTTP_ORIGIN' => 'http://localhost:8888'
    'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS' => '1'
    'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36'
    'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8'
    'HTTP_REFERER' => 'http://localhost:8888/web/customers/add'
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip, deflate, br'
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
    'PATH' => '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'
    'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => ''
    'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.0.15 mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0'
    'SERVER_NAME' => 'localhost'
    'SERVER_ADDR' => '::1'
    'SERVER_PORT' => '8888'
    'REMOTE_ADDR' => '::1'
    'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/Users/sergejandrejkin/PhpstormProjects/yii2_book'
    'SERVER_ADMIN' => 'you@example.com'
    'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/Users/sergejandrejkin/PhpstormProjects/yii2_book/web/index.php'
    'REMOTE_PORT' => '49253'
    'REDIRECT_URL' => '/web/customers/add'
    'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1'
    'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1'
    'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'POST'
    'QUERY_STRING' => ''
    'REQUEST_URI' => '/web/customers/add'
    'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/web/index.php'
    'PHP_SELF' => '/web/index.php'
    'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => 1515148203.45
    'REQUEST_TIME' => 1515148203
    'argv' => []
    'argc' => 0
]
```

Comment: Could please post the entire code of your action in your controller?

Comment: yes, sure. I've written it in the question

Comment: Can you please show stacktrace. I think problem related with configuration

Comment: What exacly means `isn't working`? It doesn't redirect you? Any error occurs? If yes, could you share this error?

Comment: @Yupik I have a form on the page after confirming this the page is reload and stay clean. But data from form is sent to DB perfectly.

Comment: @ZiyaVakhobov did it! In the question

Comment: First of all, remove your question text, paste there your `view` code, full `controller` code and add stack trace again. It's just mistake in CSRF validation and you did extreme to solve question because of `i think`...

Comment: @Yupik I pushed only view because stackOverFlow-system wants to make some changes with Controller code. Look on it pls. I think u really could help because other ideas so trivial

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump($customer->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $customer->validate() && $phone->load(Yii::$app->request->post()));die;`, put the code right before your `if` statement in action. *of course after submitting form!

Comment: @Yupik It's ok, it shows objects with data. Now I try to build my app on basic-platform from official web-site and it start's working...it's not bad for deal but still I don't know what happened with old version of app

Comment: If it shows objects with data then it's wrong, it should show one boolean value...

Answer (score 1):

I've had same issue. Considering `store(…)` method works fine, try to add `Yii::$app->end()` after redirect. So

`return $this->redirect(['index']);`

becomes

`$this->redirect(['index']);
Yii::$app->end();`

Answer (score 1):

The exception says:

```
  yii\web\BadRequestHttpException: Unable to verify your data submission.
```

This tell you 2 things:

- bad request exception (http code 400): Is a server response that is sent when the request done by the browser is invalid. Checking the exception's stacktrace you can see its thrown in the beforeAction of the actionAdd so your redirect isnt the problem, as the exception is before your code.
- Yii usually use this exception when the CSRF check is invalid, so you should check [this page](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/csrf/)

Answer (score 0):

check it out , do you have any echo before that ?

if have just clear it by `ob_end_clean();` 
if any echo or header have exist before redirect , it's wont be work !

try :

```
flush();
```

or try

```
ob_start()
```

if no one works try javascript method :

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>  window.location='http://your complete url .. '; </script>";
```

that will works 100% ,good luck .

Comment: Yes, I know about headers and 'echo', but it isn't that. Your method throws next: ob_end_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete

Comment: @AndreykinSergey I edit my answered and I know that will work 100%;

Comment: :D the javascript solution works perfectly. But I have to find the mistake in my yii2 code

Comment: @AndreykinSergey some time you have to use this method ,

Answer (score -1):

Yes please check your config settings.

```
'urlManager' => [
'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
'enableStrictParsing' => true,
'showScriptName' => false,
'rules' => [
],
```

]

Also your mod_rewrite module should be enabled.
Hope it helps!

Comment: After adding 'enableStrictParsing' yii started sent next error:An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\base\InvalidRouteException: Unable to resolve the request: site/error in /Users/sergejandrejkin/PhpstormProjects/yii2_book/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php:128
Stack trace: